# Can a hilla app be webpacked to a .js file that can then be included in another web app?

Tags: hilla

I.e, not to use the default web page from spring, but to include the webpacked .js file in another javascript app?

Comment: Hi, your question is too wide to be answered here without knowing your context in depth. You should seek advice e.g. in Vaadin's Discord channel: https://discord.com/channels/732335336448852018/1009205986646560909

Answer (score 0):

Hilla relies on the generated HTML for at least two purposes:

- Some configuration is passed through the HTML page.
- URLs for sending messages to the server are relative to the URL of the HTML page.

There is no official support for using Hilla in any other way. It might still be possible to create your own workaround to compensate for the two above factors. At the same time, this is a relatively frequently requested feature, so it's possible that support might be added at some point in the future.